# AS3 flash, Array objects are carrying over into next frame and causing null object error

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, frame

//I commented out the section that I was trying, but so far nothing has been working. I know I need to set up a loop or something of that kind to get rid of the items in the array, but I'm not sure how to get the right outcome.
THANKS SO MUCH

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


var loveXCounter: Number = 0;


healthLove_txt.text = "Wrong Words: 0";


var insideLoveXCount = new Timer(4000, 0)


insideLoveXCount.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countLoveX);


insideLoveXCount.start();


var loveXList: Array = ["Hate", "Abhor", "Vile", "Dislike", "Enmity", "Illwill", "Loath", "Neglect", "Repulse", "Resent"];

function countLoveX(e: TimerEvent) {
    var loveXName: String = loveXList[Math.floor(Math.random() * loveXList.length)];

    var loveXReference: Class = getDefinitionByName(loveXName) as Class;

    var myLoveX = new loveXReference;

    myLoveX.x = Math.random() * 700;
    myLoveX.y = -10;
    myLoveX.speed = 5;
    myLoveX.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fallingLoveX);
    addChild(myLoveX);
    loveXList.splice(loveXName, 1);
}

function fallingLoveX(e: Event): void {

    if (e.target.hitTestObject(fb_mc)) {
        e.target.visible = false;
        loveXCounter = loveXCounter + 1;
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fallingLoveX);
        healthLove_txt.text = "Wrong Words: " + loveXCounter;
        if (loveXCounter == 5) {
        while( loveXList.length > 0 )
{
    this.removeChild( loveXList[loveXList.length - 1] );
    loveXList.pop();
}
            MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(137);
            loseBook_mc.gotoAndStop("loseLove");

        }
    }

    if (e.target.y < 800) {
        e.target.y += e.target.speed;
        if (e.target.y > 800) {
            e.target.y = 800;

        }
    } else {
        e.target.visible = false;
    }
}

stop();
```

Comment: Okay I realize this might be confusing. I want the items in my array to stop entering the frame after I move to a different frame on the timeline. I am getting null object errors because they are still appearing in other frames. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the line...

```
loveXList.splice(loveXName, 1);
```

...might be causing problems. Firstly, the first parameter of the Array .splice method should be of type int. You are passing in a String. To remedy that, store the randomly selected index of the loveXList Array in an int variable, use that get your loveXName String and use the int again to splice out the correct String from the loveXList Array, ie:

```
var randomIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * loveXList.length);
var loveXName: String = loveXList[randomIndex];
...
loveXList.splice(randomIndex, 1);
```

Secondly, you will quickly run out of Strings to splice out of the loveXList Array so, at the start of the countLoveX function, check if loveXList.length>0. If loveXList.length==0 you may want to stop the timer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, still doesn't seem to want to work though. Here is my updated code:

Comment: var insideLoveXCount = new Timer(4000, 10)
function countLoveX(e: TimerEvent) {
 if (loveXList.length > 0) {
 var randomLoveXIndex: int = Math.floor(Math.random() * loveXList.length);
  var loveXName: String = loveXList[randomLoveXIndex];
var loveXReference: Class = getDefinitionByName(loveXName) as Class;
var myLoveX = new loveXReference; 
 myLoveX.x = Math.random() * 700;
 myLoveX.y = -10;
 myLoveX.speed = 5;
 myLoveX.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fallingLoveX);
  addChild(myLoveX);
}
 if (loveXList.length == 0) {
  insideLoveXCount.stop();
 }
 loveXList.splice(randomLoveXIndex, 1);
}

Comment: You should .splice the Array immediately after the addChild line. Otherwise your splice call may not have access to randomLoveXIndex - At the very least it will still try to 'splice' when the Array's length is 0! Also you MAY need to add a pair of brackets () to the line var myLoveX = new loveXReference()